# Problem uploading packages

Tags: errors, packages

I am using WinEdt 8.2 at the university computer. Since a while ago it started giving me some errors (copy of log below) like

```
*! LaTeX Error: File `relsize.sty' not found.*

*! LaTeX Error: File `threeparttable.sty' not found.*

*! LaTeX Error: File `comment.sty' not found.*
```

I used to worked perfectly fine. Moreover, if I use TexWork, it runs smoothly.

Any ideas?

thanks!!

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "congestion_art_v13"
Startup Folder: G:\My Documents\_downloads\congestion\latex

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: congestion_art_v13.aux
The style file: agsm.bst
Database file #1: example_v1.bib
Warning--empty institution in ssn2013
Warning--empty institution in maternity2013nao
Warning--empty institution in world2015statement
(There were 3 warnings)
```

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "congestion_art_v13.tex"
Startup Folder: G:\My Documents\_downloads\congestion\latex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./congestion_art_v13.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 20 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `relsize.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `threeparttable.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `comment.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)

! Package caption Error: For a successful cooperation we need at least version
(caption)                `2003/06/13 v3.0' of package threeparttable,
(caption)                but only version
(caption)                `'
(caption)                is available.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1763 }{}

? 
)) (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty

Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.

) (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rotating/rotating.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/ragged2e.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/hhline.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `chngcntr.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(./congestion_art_v13.aux) (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./congestion_art_v13.out) (./congestion_art_v13.out)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros [1{c:/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pd
ftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4] [5]
<article1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=158, 397.485pt x 289.08pt>
<use article1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
<article2-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=159, 397.485pt x 289.08pt>
<use article2-eps-converted-to.pdf> [6 <./article1-eps-converted-to.pdf> <./art
icle2-eps-converted-to.pdf>]

! LaTeX Error: Environment threeparttable undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.177 \begin{threeparttable}

? 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 193--193
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Sunday&

! LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 173 ended by \end{threeparttable}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.198  \end{threeparttable}

? 
[7]

! LaTeX Error: Environment threeparttable undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.212 \begin{threeparttable}

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

Comment: What do mean by `uploading`? I think you mean `updating`, but it looks that either your distribution installation (on the university computer) is corrupted or incomplete

Comment: Did you do a full installation or just a minimal one?

Answer (score 1):

It just means that you don't have those packages, You are using texlive 2015 so a command such as

```
tlmgr update relsize
```

should fetch that package and install it locally.